# d3.js - how do chords become visible again on mouseout event

Tags: d3.js

I am adapting the following [chords example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/) using d3.js to display relationships between groups. Can somebody explain how the chords appear back after they have faded out.

I'm interested in hooking up a handler into this to display information and have it go away on mouseout.

There is a mouseover handler that adds a *fade* class to the path element but I don't see any code to remove it.

```
<path class="chord fade" d=<elided> style="fill: rgb(247, 129, 191);">
    <title>Financial District → Western Addition: 1.1%Western Addition → Financial District: 1.1%</title>
</path>
```

Despite this when I mouse out of a group the chords that were faded out reappear. My question is how is it achieved?

For convenience here is a jsfiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/huynhjl/hxby165d/7/

I am aware of this question/answer [D3.js Chord diagram - Have text appear/disappear when hovering over an arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784801/d3-js-chord-diagram-have-text-appear-disappear-when-hovering-over-an-arc), but I am wondering how the original showcase does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemingly odd behavior is accomplished with the css.

What's happening in the script is that when one of the paths fires the `mouseover` event, the handler selects *all* of the chords, and for each one, switches the `fade` class off or on, based on whether that chord is connected to the hovered element or not.

So, how is the `fade` class being handled? Check out the selector that actually hides the elements:

```
#circle:hover path.fade {
    display: none;
}
```

What that css rule is really saying is:

*when there is a <path> element with a class of "fade" that is a descendant of a hovered element with an id of "circle", set its "display" property to "none".*

In other words, the `fade` class doesn't hide the elements unless the `g` element that has id `#circle` is being hovered. Therefore, when the mouse is no longer over that group, the paths are visible again, even if they still have the `fade` class.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Bootstrap on your site, then this same problem may occur even with adding

```
#circle:hover path.fade {
  display:none;
}
```

This is due to Bootstrap already having a fade class!

To remedy this, I changed my D3 class to be "fadechord" and now have:

```
#circle:hover path.fadechord {
  display:none;
}
```

and then in the mouseover listener I have:

```
            function mouseover(d, i) {
                chord.classed("fadechord", function(p) {
                    return p.source.index != i
                            && p.target.index != i;
                });
            }
```

Comment: Excellent! After much head scratching, this solution saved me mucho time! Gracias!

Comment: Thank you so much! Just changing the class name worked perfectly! I was totally clueless as to why it wasn't doing what I thought I was telling it to do :)

Comment: Thank you! Kudos Darren!